# VertTwoFingerScroll and VertEdgeScroll not settable via xorg.conf

Tags: xorg, trackpad

I've just upgraded to Saucy (this was working in Raring). I've tried rebooting.

Here's `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier      "Touchpad"
Driver          "synaptics"
MatchIsTouchpad "on"
Option          "PressureMotionMinZ" "60"
Option      "MaxTapMove" "4"
Option      "PalmDetect" "1"
Option      "VertTwoFingerScroll" "1"
Option      "VertEdgeScroll" "0"
EndSection
```

And here's the output from `synclient`:

```
LeftEdge                = 100
RightEdge               = 2408
TopEdge                 = 71
BottomEdge              = 1249
FingerLow               = 1
FingerHigh              = 1
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 4
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = 56
HorizScrollDelta        = 56
VertEdgeScroll          = 1
HorizEdgeScroll         = 1
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 0
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.0705716
TouchpadOff             = 2
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 2
RBCornerButton          = 3
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 1
TapButton2              = 3
TapButton3              = 0
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 1
ClickFinger3            = 0
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
PalmDetect              = 1
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 60
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
ResolutionDetect        = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 1
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 14
VertHysteresis          = 14
ClickPad                = 0
```

Notice that `PressureMotionMinZ`, `MaxTapMove` and `PalmDetect` are as specified in `xorg.conf`, but `VertEdgeScroll` and `VertTwoFingerScroll` aren't. I can set them temporarily via `synclient VertEdgeScroll=0` and `synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1`, but these changes are lost when I reboot. What's the best way of fixing this?

Comment: I may have found something in [another comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26290/50-synaptics-conf-options-not-working/81104#81104). Quoting Nikita Volkov: “Run dconf-editor (apt-get install it if you have to), go to org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.mouse, uncheck active.”. I can't reboot at the moment, but don't bother answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to repeat my previous comment: [Nikita Volkov's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26290/50-synaptics-conf-options-not-working/81104#comment-146919):

Run `dconf-editor` (`apt-get install dconf-editor` if you have to install it), go to `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.mouse`, uncheck `active`.

Comment: in gnome 3.14 / ubuntu 15.04, the entire settings-daemon in org.gnome doesn't appear to exist after a fresh install.