# Why is my two finger scrolling (VertTwoFingerScroll) on Lenovo Thinkpad touchpad not saving on reboot?

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, synaptics

On my Ubuntu Mate 14.04, using Lenovo Thinkpad T440, I go to GPointing Device Settings, SynPS/2 Synaptics Touchpad, scrolling. Enable vertical scrolling is checked. Enable vertical scrolling when dragging with two fingers is also checked.

```
synclient -l
```

shows that VertTwoFingerScroll = 1.

vertical scrolling works with two fingers.  But when I reboot and run synclient again, it shows VertTwoFingerScroll = 0.

How do I save the configuration permanently?
Thanks

Comment: I have tried the solution http://askubuntu.com/questions/362345/verttwofingerscroll-and-vertedgescroll-not-settable-via-xorg-conf but it didn't work for me.

Comment: When I use Cinnamon desktop (instead of Mate), the two-finger scrolling setting for the touchpad is saved between reboots.