# How to set up a separate X server for the Oculus Rift?

Tags: 14.04, xorg, screen

Oculus SDK version 0.4.3+ comes with an experimental Linux support for the Oculus Rift DK2. The documentation mentions two general options to run the Rift:

1. running the Rift in a twinview configuration using `xrandr` (or one of its graphical front-ends)
2. running the Rift as a separate X server.

My question is: What are the required steps to configure a separate X server for the Rift? In particular:

- [Apparently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there), modern X11 versions no longer have a `xorg.conf` file. Is creating a `xorg.conf` file actually required? Or is it possible to make the necessary adjustments in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` or `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, as suggested by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/27017)?
- If it is necessary to create an `xorg.conf`: How do I obtain and exactly replicate all non-Rift-related settings of my current default configuration?
- If I understand the [xorg.conf man page](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml) correctly, it is required to define a new `ServerLayout` section for the Rift, since a `ServerLayout` is the top level definition of every X server. The `ServerLayout` itself binds a `Screen` and an `InputDevice` section. The `Screen` section further binds a `Device` section (a graphics device) and a `Monitor` section. Therefore, we probably need at least a `SeverLayout`, `InputDevice`, `Device`, and `Monitor` section. How would these sections typically look like for an Oculus Rift X server?

Comment: Maybe something like: http://askubuntu.com/a/281685/47291 at least for getting a default file